# Images won't be uploaded with the cakephp-upload behavoir

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I wan't to build a simple upload functionality inside my cakephp 3.x application. I have used the [cakephp-upload behavior](http://cakephp-upload.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html). On this moment I can save all needed data into the database, but the image won't be uploaded. I've checked some related articles here on stackoverflow but the are mostly for cakephp 2.x and not for version 3.x.

**The view looks like this:**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create($form, ['type' => 'file', 'id' => 'form', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'url' => '/storages/form/content/' . $formId]); ?>

// some other input fields

<?php echo $this->Form->input('photo', ['type' => 'file']); ?>
<?php echo $this->form->end(); ?>
```

**The function to save all photo related stuff to the database looks like this:**

```
// the $array consists of this data
    [
        'data||1' => 'data',
        'photo' => [
            'tmp_name' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpHbVBQz',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'name' => 'Screen Shot 2017-08-22 at 14.26.17.png',
            'type' => 'image/png',
            'size' => (int) 163117
        ]
]

 private function addContent($array) {
        $form = $this->getHighestFormId();

        foreach ($array as $field => $value) {
            if ($value != null) {
                // create new entity
                $containerContent = $this->StoragecontainerContent->newEntity();

                // explode field name and container_block_element_id
                $explodedField = explode("||", $field); // [0] field, [1] container_block_element_id

                // remove the automatic generated _ character from the string and replace it by a whitespace
                // $replacedName = str_replace("_", " ", $explodedField[0]);

                // create array
                $data = [
                    'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'),
                    'form_id' => $form->maxFormId + 1,
                    'storagecontainer_block_element_id' => $explodedField[1],
                    'identifier' => $explodedField[0],
                    'content' => $value
                ];

                // patch data
                $containerContent = $this->StoragecontainerContent->patchEntity($containerContent, $data);

                // safe value
                $this->StoragecontainerContent->save($containerContent);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Finally, my table class looks like this:**

```
class StoragecontainerContentTable extends Table {

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config) {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('storagecontainer_content');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Josegonzalez/Upload.Upload', [
            'photo' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'dir' => 'photo_dir',
                    'size' => 'photo_size',
                    'type' => 'photo_type'
                ],
                'nameCallback' => function ($data, $settings) {
                    return strtolower($data['name']);
                },
                'transformer' =>  function ($table, $entity, $data, $field, $settings) {
                    $extension = pathinfo($data['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                    // Store the thumbnail in a temporary file
                    $tmp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'upload') . '.' . $extension;

                    // Use the Imagine library to DO THE THING
                    $size = new \Imagine\Image\Box(40, 40);
                    $mode = \Imagine\Image\ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_INSET;
                    $imagine = new \Imagine\Gd\Imagine();

                    // Save that modified file to our temp file
                    $imagine->open($data['tmp_name'])
                        ->thumbnail($size, $mode)
                        ->save($tmp);

                    // Now return the original *and* the thumbnail
                    return [
                        $data['tmp_name'] => $data['name'],
                        $tmp => 'thumbnail-' . $data['name'],
                    ];
                },
                'deleteCallback' => function ($path, $entity, $field, $settings) {
                    // When deleting the entity, both the original and the thumbnail will be removed
                    // when keepFilesOnDelete is set to false
                    return [
                        $path . $entity->{$field},
                        $path . 'thumbnail-' . $entity->{$field}
                    ];
                },
                'keepFilesOnDelete' => false
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not build a custom dataset and save that, there's actually nothing special that you need to do in the saving process, that's why it's not in the docs.

All you need to do is to use the configured name in the form as you're already doing it, and patch the entity with the request data without any modifications, then save it and the upload behavior will do the rest, ie if `$array` is the raw request data, pass it directly to `patchEntity()`.

Comment: But is it possible to let the behavior save the data inside a other table? Beqouse in the examples it's saved inside a user table and that isn't what I want.

Comment: @CodeWhisperer Of course that's possible, the data will be saved to whatever table the behavior is attached to.

Comment: I've changed my question. Now the behavoir is coupled to the related table but how can I read the photo element and insert this in another table?

Comment: @CodeWhisperer Now your question is very different, and my answer doesn't make too much sense anymore. It's unclear what you want/need to do with the upload, as in your example there's only one `photo`, but your code acts as if there can be multiple `StoragecontainerContent` elements.

Comment: I think I'm misunderstand your answer sorry for the confusion. In my question there can be multiple content elements that must be saved inside the `storagecontainer_content ` this is where the `foreach` stands for. There is always one photo in total and that photo must be saved inside a table like `storagecontainer_photos`.

Comment: @CodeWhisperer you might want to take a look at https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage that was built around the idea of handling files as a separate entity in the system that can be attached to anything. It's not the most simple but IMHO the best abstracted file handling solution. Disclaimer: I wrote it.